# работа с WHERE в SQL

Tags: sql-server

Помогите пожалуйста разабраться. При выборке условий WHERE не выводит строки, числа работают. SQL ошибок не выдаёт.[image: скрипт проги]

Comment: Дык ведь кириллица... `N'Олеся'` как минимум.

Comment: Покажите структуру таблицы. В частности, какой тип данных у поля Name? Если вдруг char или nchar, то у них пробелы в конце строки будут.

Comment: У поля Nane тип nvanchar